# Image field as part of the FieldGroup in Vaadin7

Tags: java, image, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a requirement to display the image as part of the [`FieldGroup`](http://vaadin.com/download/prerelease/7.0/7.0.0/7.0.0.alpha2/docs/api/com/vaadin/data/fieldgroup/FieldGroup.html). This is for the functionality where the Image appears as normal on a web page, when in edit mode I need to edit this image value by providing an 'upload' option.

I have a Pojo with a property of type `com.vaadin.ui.Image` along with the other String and Integer values.

```
public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

I need to work this Image as a normal form element, for example when I edit a form, I have an editable [`TextField`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/TextField.html) to type in the `String` value and change it, the same way I intend to display an upload button where I would have an option to replace the existing image.

I have tried using [EasyUploads addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/easyuploads) for this purpose by intercepting the build method of `FieldGroup` and specifying the Image field as of type `org.vaadin.easyuploads.UploadField`

Like this;

```
 @Override
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    protected <T extends Field> T build(String caption, Class<?> dataType,
            Class<T> fieldType) throws BindException {

        T field = super.build(caption, dataType, fieldType);
        if (caption.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
            final UploadField imageField = new UploadField() {
                @Override
                protected void updateDisplay() {
                    final byte[] pngData = (byte[]) getValue();
                    String filename = getLastFileName();
                    String mimeType = getLastMimeType();
                    long filesize = getLastFileSize();
                    if (mimeType.equals("image/jpeg")) {
                        StreamSource imagesource = new ImageSource(pngData);
                        StreamResource resource = new StreamResource(
                                imagesource, "Uploaded File");

                        Embedded embedded = new Embedded("Image:" + filename
                                + "(" + filesize + " bytes)", resource);
                        getRootLayout().addComponent(embedded);
                    } else {
                        super.updateDisplay();
                    }
                }
            };
            imageField.setFieldType(FieldType.BYTE_ARRAY);
...
```

This however fails to display the already available image, errors out with the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property type class com.vaadin.ui.Image is not compatible with UploadField
    at org.vaadin.easyuploads.UploadField.setPropertyDataSource(UploadField.java:1021)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.bind(FieldGroup.java:265)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.BeanFieldGroup.bind(BeanFieldGroup.java:167)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.FieldGroup.setItemDataSource(FieldGroup.java:106)
    at com.vaadin.data.fieldgroup.BeanFieldGroup.setItemDataSource(BeanFieldGroup.java:142)
```

Is there a cleaner way of using an Image as part of the FieldGroup in vaadin 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest replacing in your Pojo the Image instance with a simple byte[], because looking through the UploadField code, I can't see any natural way of converting the result from the upload (which is either a byte[] or a File instance) into something else, using the FieldGroup like you asked.

If you look inside AbstractField.getValue(), you will see that the model value is eventually passed through a settable converter which would have normally helped you in this case (see com.vaadin.data.util.converter.Converter). But I think you are pretty much forced to use byte[] if you want to bind a image bean to the FieldGroup.

Anyway, if you **DO** replace with byte[] the following steps will help you:

1. Create a custom FieldGroupFieldFactory that will create an UploadField if you want to bind to a byte[] property + passes a ValueChangeListener for the UploadField is done uploading:

   public class ImageEnhancedFieldFactory extends DefaultFieldGroupFieldFactory {

   ```
   private Property.ValueChangeListener fileUploadedListener;

   private ImageEnhancedFieldFactory(Property.ValueChangeListener fileUploadedListener) {
       this.fileUploadedListener = fileUploadedListener;
   }

   @Override
   public <T extends Field> T createField(Class<?> type, Class<T> fieldType) {
       if (byte[].class.equals(type)) {
           UploadField uploadField = new UploadField(UploadField.StorageMode.MEMORY);
           uploadField.setFieldType(UploadField.FieldType.BYTE_ARRAY);
           uploadField.setButtonCaption("Change image");
           uploadField.addListener(fileUploadedListener);
           return (T) uploadField;
       }
       return super.createField(type, fieldType);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create an Image instance that shows the content of the byte[] from the pojo:

   ```
       final ImagePojo imagePojo = new ImagePojo();
   imagePojo.setName("superman");
   imagePojo.setImageContent(new byte[0]);

   BeanItem<ImagePojo> item = new BeanItem<ImagePojo>(imagePojo);


   final StreamResource imageResource = new StreamResource(new StreamResource.StreamSource() {
       @Override
       public InputStream getStream() {
           return new ByteArrayInputStream(imagePojo.getImageContent());
       }
   }, "myimage");
   imageResource.setCacheTime(0);

   final Image image = new Image("Image", imageResource);
   addComponent(image);
   ```

**NOTE:** its necessary to set the cache time to 0 in order to prevent the browser from caching the resource( see https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.embedded.html in the section **Generating and Reloading Images**)

3.Create the FieldGroup (with the new FieldGroupFieldFactory set) and bind to the properties of the pojo, including the one that contains the image content (the byte[]):

```
FieldGroup fieldGroup = new FieldGroup(item);
    fieldGroup.setFieldFactory(new ImageEnhancedFieldFactory(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
            String filename = "myfilename-" + df.format(new Date()) + ".jpg";
            imagePojo.setImageContent((byte[])event.getProperty().getValue());
            image.markAsDirty();
            imageResource.setFilename(filename);
        }
    }));

    addComponent(fieldGroup.buildAndBind("Image name", "name"));
    addComponent(fieldGroup.buildAndBind("Image content", "imageContent"));
```

I left a snippet on Gist of a component that you can paste in you UI and play around if you need (https://gist.github.com/gabrielruiu/9953279)